# Powerful audio lib

Tags: c++, audio

Can you recommend a powerful audio lib?

I need it to timestrech & pitchshift independently, as well as give me full access to the raw audio data and let me stream bytes into its pipeline.

Other effects like eq, filtering, distortion are a plus.

Needs to be accessible from C++ / Linux.

Maybe gstreamer, xine or mplayer would work? Or what would you suggest.

Answer (score 4):

I think [**FMod**](http://www.fmod.org/) is widely recognized as one of the most powerful audio engine available for free until you do something commercial with it, and cross-platform, like in console-mac-pc cross-platform.

Now, [**OpenAL**](http://connect.creativelabs.com/openal/default.aspx) is worth giving a try.

Answer (score 1):

OpenAL, PulseAudio, JACK, and Phonon, I believe, each have these features in some form.

Answer (score 1):

If you willing to pay for it Miles is very nice.  I can't recommend FMOD for much outside of hobby projects.  It's had some truly nasty bugs, and I've seen new versions introduce as many as they fix.

Answer (score 0):

I've used [soundtouch](http://www.surina.net/soundtouch/) in the past.  Focused on changing speed/pitch/etc.

Answer (score -1):

[ALSA](http://www.alsa-project.org/main/index.php/Main_Page) looks like the big one.

[JACK](http://jackaudio.org/) for Linux also looks promising.

Comment: alsa has pitchshifting and timestretching now??

Comment: Perhaps not in and of itself, but one of the list of 50+ applications on the ALSA site probably does.

Comment: Well I didn't ask about applications

Comment: Haha we had the exact same amount of rep before you got downvoted :)

Comment: Hilarious.  I downvote *incorrect* answers, not ones that are not exactly what I was looking for.  Sorry for trying to help out.

Comment: heh, now, ladies, be nice. :)  FWIW I would side with the OP here, minus the part about Dave's attitude. ALSA and JACK are not related to this question at all, nor is a big list of links. That's not incorrect per se, but it's also not helpful, so if you don't know, don't answer.

Comment: Well now this is interesting: my answer included JACK but but it got downvoted.  The top answer includes JACK.  Methinks there is a double standard here.  If my answer was *partly correct* then it should at least be left alone, not downvoted.

Comment: Life ain't fair.  But then again, I also don't think that the currently-voted top answer is really great either.  At any rate, JACK and ALSA are both transport layers; neither one is an audio engine.